# Using ng-repeat value as filter for nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an outer div that I want to repeat for each cats in art.Categories.
While that repeat loop happens, I want to take the value from the ng-repeat and use it to create a nested ng-repeat. This nested ng-repeat will continue until it runs out of items, then return to the outside ng-repeat, which will continue the process.

My issue is I can't use `{{cats.id}}` as the filter for the sub-Div.

```
    <div ng-repeat="cats in art.Categories" class="tab-pane" ng-class="{active: $index == 0}" id="{{cats.id}}">

            <div ng-repeat="arts in art.Articles | filter: { ids: '{{cats.id}}' }" class="entity_container"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Try `filter: { ids: cats.id }` (no quotes, no curly braces); and of course the `arts` must have a field named `ids`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commenter mentioned, a solution is to remove the curly braces. In my example, that means just writing `cats.id`. As an aside, I need to implement UI's native tabs directives.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ng-show="arts.ids==cats.id"
```